Multiple annual inspections failed to find a problem that is now showing up - is there any recourse?
I purchased a 1977 Cessna 150M about 3 years ago. The aircraft is currently undergoing an annual inspection.
The inspector has determined that the engine serial number does not match the engine logbooks (and is therefore not airworthy). The aircraft has gone through many annual inspections. The report from the pre-purchase inspection I had performed clearly states "made sure all SN#'s match". Do I have any recourse? Am I just screwed?

you should see if Saavy Aviation will help you.

This sounds more like a legal question than an aviation one. What liability did the agreement with the pre-purchase inspector have? I'd seek the advice of a lawyer personally!

Per the other comment, you should email Mike Busch (Saavy) and ask him if there's a way for an AI to reconstruct a log from the other data like FAA records, or demonstrate that the mismatch is a writing error by somebody. Maybe you can find an AI who will do it for you. MIke is very good at responding to questions from aircraft owners.

I've got a note out to Savvy (coincendentially) I paid Savvy to manage the pre-buy inspection process.
